# xsl:cdata elements inside xsl:element

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata

I am trying to get the following output :

```
<name><![CDATA[ SomeNameHere ]]></name>
```

using the following xslt :

```
  <xsl:element name="name"> 
            <xsl:cdata>
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/> 
            </xsl:cdata>
  </xsl:element>
```

But while compiling I get the following exception :

```
'xsl:cdata' cannot be a child of the 'xsl:element' element.
```

How can I insert cdata elements inside an xml node then?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such think as `<xsl:cdata>`

If your `<xsl:output/>` includes name among the elements listed in the `cdata-section-elements` attributes, then it will use CDATA sections for all such elements.

If you needed it in one particular case, you could kludge with `disable-output-escaping` though really you shouldn't have any need for this.

Comment: Just as I said above. Have cdata-section-elements="name message" in your <xsl:output element>. (use prefix if appropriate).